# magento 2 seperated parent and sub categories dropdowns

Tags: magento-2.1, category, menu, sub-categories

I want to show different input dropdown that seperate parent categories and subcategories.
Indeed, the first dropdown shows parent categories, the second dropdown empty at first sight, then loaded subcategories of selected parent category